# React-Native metro bundler can't serve any file

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, react-native, metro-bundler

The metro bundler can resolve the dependencies graph(the app starts in emulator) but can't resolve any assets so all images in the app are missing.

This problem happens only after I upgraded from react-native@0.57 to 0.59

```
Looking for JS files in
   /Users/name/app/MyApp/artifacts
   /Users/name/app/MyApp/node_modules

warning: the transform cache was reset.
Loading dependency graph, done.
 DELTA  [android, dev] artifacts/index.js ▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓ 100.0% (2921/2921), done.

 MAP  [android, dev] artifacts/index.js ▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓ 100.0% (1/1), done.


::ffff:127.0.0.1 - - [30/Aug/2019:06:27:17 +0000] "GET /node_modules/my-assets/artifacts/assets/images/Logo.png?platform=android&hash=someHash HTTP/1.1" 404 221 "-" "okhttp/3.12.1"
```

**^^^ issue appears on navigating to any view that contains `<Image source=... />`**

The module `my-assets` does exist and contains all assets needed

To start: `node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start --reset-cache --projectRoot artifacts`

The `artifacts` contains transpiled `.js` code from `.ts`

My file structure looks like this

```sh
.
├── artifacts # transpiled js files
├── node_modules #npm modules
└── src # ts files
```

bundler server output

metro.config.js

```
module.exports = {
    watchFolders: [path.join(__dirname, 'node_modules')],
    transformer: {
        getTransformOptions: async () => ({
            transform: {
                experimentalImportSupport: false,
                inlineRequires: false
            }
        })
    },
    resolver: {
        blacklistRE: blacklist([       /node_modules\/.*\/node_modules\/react-native\/.*/]),
        assetRegistryPath: path.resolve('node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Image/AssetRegistry')
    }
}
```

dependencies:

```
my-app@1.0 /Users/name/app/MyApp
├── metro@0.48.5  extraneous
└─┬ react-native@0.59.4
  └─┬ @react-native-community/cli@1.11.2
    ├── metro@0.51.1
    └─┬ metro-config@0.51.1
      └── metro@0.51.1  deduped
```

I also tried goto url in browser but also go 404 for both following request

```
http://localhost:8081/node_modules/my-assets/artifacts/assets/images/Logo.png?platform=android&hash=someHash

http://localhost:8081/node_modules/metro/src/Bundler/util.js # request to any js file also return 404
```

-- update --

Cleaning cache and removing $TMPDIR does not help

Comment: where did you find docs about this `blacklistRE` property?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*I see notification and then realized I asked this before*

I don't remember how did I figured that out but there in my commit message this [issue](https://github.com/facebook/metro/issues/322) come into my sight, and they mentioned at [comment](https://github.com/facebook/metro/issues/322#issuecomment-443221801):

> Very soon we want to force all watch folders to be inside the project root of metro, this way Metro can safely use the project root as the root of the http server that provides the assets and this will fix this issue

---

To solve that, I had to change my file structure from

```sh
.
├── artifacts
├── node_modules
├── package.json
├── src
│   ├── index.ts
```

To:

```sh
.
├── artifacts
├── index.js # added this root level entry file
├── node_modules
├── src
│   ├── index.ts
```

What's in the newly added `index.js` was just `require('./artifacts/index.js')` which works as the entry file for metro. And start the server from `.` using `npx react-native start --skipflow --reset-cache` to make sure everything is inside the root.

(as mentioned in OP, we use `node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start --reset-cache --projectRoot artifacts` to start metro server, so you can change `--projectRoot` to point to a proper dir to archive the same)

Answer (score 2):

Try to clean your cache and try again

```
rm -rf $TMPDIR/react-native-packager-cache-*
rm -rf $TMPDIR/metro-bundler-cache-* 
rm -rf $TMPDIR/haste-*;
yarn cache clean
```

Comment: command `rm -rf $TMPDIR/haste-*;` worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this command

```
npm cache clean
```